# While importing train_test_split from from sklearn.model_selection, why am I getting the error "AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

While running this cell in Jupyter Notebook I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py in <module>
      1 """ python inspection/code generation API """
----> 2 from .code import Code  # noqa
      3 from .code import ExceptionInfo  # noqa
      4 from .code import filter_traceback  # noqa
      5 from .code import Frame  # noqa

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py in <module>
    390 
    391 
--> 392 @attr.s(repr=False)
    393 class ExceptionInfo(Generic[_E]):
    394     """ wraps sys.exc_info() objects and offers

AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

Can somebody explain what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter these commands on the terminal or in a notebook:

```
pip uninstall attr
pip install attrs
```

Comment: I had attr listed in my setup.py file and it caused pytest to throw the attr does not have attribute s error -- this fixed it!  thank you~